# Quick Question on linear matrix transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

I'm asked to give a geometric description of this matrix, by first finding the angle of rotation, but i can't input in the formula because the denominator would be 0 which leaves us with no solution.

The answer to the question is: The matrix represents a scaling by a factor of 4 in the x-direction and a scaling by a factor of 2 in
the y-direction, followed by an anticlockwise rotation by an angle of pi/2.

I was wondering how they reached this solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\pmatrix{ 0 & -2 \\ 4 & \phantom-0}
=
\pmatrix{ 0 & -1 \\ 1 & \phantom-0}
\pmatrix{ 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 2}
$$
Can you now interpret these two matrices?